# Dithering Circuit using an Op-amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, frequency

I am reading and trying to understand this [Application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua704/slua704.pdf?ts=1617195358106&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) from TI on how the dithering circuit works.

I can deduce that the Op-amp acts as a schmitt trigger but there's no details on how the frequency change is effected. Can someone help me with the working of the circuit on how the frequency change is effected with the schmitt trigger?

And also, can someone explain how is the calculation obtained? Why is the 7kHz/65kH multiplied with the 45uA current?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they are saying is that to make the UC28180 dither its operating frequency there is an external 2 kHz triangle wave generator (below) that is attached to the FREQ pin: -

[image]

And, because the operating frequency is set by the current out of the FREQ pin, the dithering oscillator can modulate this by taking, in effect an AC current from the FREQ pin. The main central oscillation frequency (65 kHz) is set by RT but, if a little current is taken and put back through the 100 kΩ resistor then the main chip's oscillation frequency will "dither".

To set the basic 65 kHz operating frequency, RT must draw 45.87 μA and, to make this 7 kHz higher or lower, a current of plus or minus 4.94 μA must be taken through the 100 kΩ resistor. That current is: -

$$ \pm 45.87\text{ } \mu A \times\dfrac{7}{65} = \pm 4.9398\text{ } \mu A$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think too narrow and miss the main parts of the reasoning. Thanks for guiding me.

Comment: It can be a long road, but it's still worth the journey.

Comment: Basically the voltage out of FREQ is internally regulated to be 1.5 volts. This means that it's easy to calculate RT based on the current it draws and, that current defines the main operating frequency. Given that the dither op-amp circuit has a nominal DC output of 1.5 volts (due to V1, R1 and R2) and couples to FREQ via 100 kohm, there is little to no current from the 100 kohm feeding RT when the oscillator voltage is at its mid-point.

Comment: sorry, i tried to wrap my head around the above point which you mentioned. but still i am not able to get the clarity.. could you break it a little more simpler for me..

Comment: The 1.5V sources and sinks the extra 4.9uA current?

Comment: If you disconnected the 100 k resistor that joins onto RT, the nominal DC voltage coming out from that 100 k resistor is 1.5 volts. This matches the nominal value produced by the UC chip on the FREQ pin so, when you reconnect the 100 k ohm, in effect, only an AC dither current flows through that 100 kohm.

Comment: Ok thank you. So, the 1.5V internal to the IC, would act as a current source sometimes and as well as a current sink sometimes. Am I correct?

Comment: The IC (FREQ) is delivering an average of about 45 uA from the pin, and due to dithering, this will cyclically (2 kHz) rise up to about 50 uA and fall as low as about 40 uA but, the FREQ pin is still sourcing that current to RT and the 100 kohm. The current from the FREQ pin never goes below zero micro amp.

Answer (score 0):

> I can deduce that the Op-amp acts as a schmitt trigger but there's no details on how the frequency change is effected. Can someone help me with the working of the circuit on how the frequency change is effected with the schmitt trigger?

The op-amp circuit is connected to the chip's frequency control pin.  That pin is designed to have a resistor to ground, which -- reading between the lines on the data sheet -- appears to be held at a constant voltage, with the frequency being dependent on the current through the resistor.

> And also, can someone explain how is the calculation obtained? Why is the 7kHz/65kH multiplied with the 45uA current?

Again, I suspect from what the data sheet *does* say, that what the data sheet *doesn't* say is that there's a current out of that pin, and that current controls the frequency.  I didn't read the app note, but that's telling you how much current to expect.

Comment: How can the frequency depend on current and not voltage?

Comment: @MissMulan The frequency *is* actuated by the current while held in internal feedback at a constant voltage; the current in/out of the pin is dictated by the voltage at the far end of the resistor (or by whatever active device is connected to the pin). In normal circumstances, the frequency would be set by changing the value of the resistor, which changes the current. Totally plausible since that pin might be connected to a current mirror internally, which subsequently feeds a VCO. Nobody is making stuff up.

Comment: @MissMulan that sounds like a good topic for a second question -- ask, and ye shall be educated.